# fancy box ajax php log in example not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, fancybox

Trying out the login form **example (number 5)**:

[fancybox](http://fancybox.net/blog/)

It doesn't seem to work, when clicking to verify data it just reloads page. As far as I understand it, ajax is supposed to avoid this very thing.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciate, I'm sure it is a relatively simply issue.

I literally just copied and pasted the code. the 'mail.php' is currently not really doing anything, but first and foremost I am looking to trigger the "#login_error" which should occur when the #login_name and #login_pass have a length of less than one. As it stands the page just refreshes.

code for reference nonetheless:
        the js -

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("#tip5").fancybox({
    'scrolling'     : 'no',
    'titleShow'     : false,
    'onClosed'      : function() {
        $("#login_error").hide();
    }
});

$("#login_form").bind("submit", function() {

    if ($("#login_name").val().length < 1 || $("#login_pass").val().length < 1) {
        $("#login_error").show();
        $.fancybox.resize();
        return false;
    }

    $.fancybox.showActivity();

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache   : false,
        url     : "mail.php",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});

    });
```

the html -

```
      <a id="tip5" href="#login_form">test</a>

<div style="display:none">
    <form id="login_form" method="post" action="">
                <p id="login_error">Please, enter data</p>
            <p>
                <label for="login_name">Login: </label>
                <input type="text" id="login_name" name="login_name" size="30" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="login_pass">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" id="login_pass" name="login_pass" size="30" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <em>Leave empty so see resizing</em>
            </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have jquery library on your page?

Comment: yeah absolutely.        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: ajax may not work properly when running locally, you may need to upload your files on a server.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add file in following order

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

otherwise your code is correct

Comment: that's the strange part. I have all added in and as far as I can tell it really should be working, but it isn't. I'm hesitant to share links here, but I'm starting to wonder if the issue has to do with the webhost.

Comment: Check whether you have put your file in correct folder and Your fancybox javascript file path is correct or not.